# Rails 4 : Routes match, id not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently writing my first app with Rails 4, following the tutorial. 
Having almost finished the User part (controller, view & model ), I wanted to match a route like /profile, to 'users#show'
So i did :

```
ressources :users
get 'profile' => 'users#show'
```

The problem is in my controller :

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

When i got to the URL /profile, I got this error

> Couldn't find User without an ID

I've read the guides and I thought the params were passed along but it doesn't seems so ..
It must be a stupid mistake but i dont find it.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a ID placeholder in the URL like this:

> get 'profile/:id' => 'users#show'

Now you can call the URL like

> "profile/12"

and you can access it in your controller as

> params[:id]

Check the docs on routing here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted but i now realize that my problem description was a bit short !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found it my self. Indeed it was a bit stupid.
Since I have followed the tutorial, I implemented the SessionControllers, with a remember_token sent with each request to find the signed in user. That's what I needed to change in my user controller so it looks like this :

```
def show
    if params[:id]
        @user = User.find(params[:id]
    else
        @user = current_user # method from session helper from tutorial
    end
end
```

So now when I type /profile , for a logged in user, it would redirect to his profile & and when we type profile/4, we would see the profile of the user with ID 4, (by adding like in the next answer :

```
get 'profile/:id' => 'users#show'
```